# Moving from a sub in the lower heirarchy, to a higher sub, such as sub main()

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

The title already suggests it, but I have recently started visual basic programming for the command line on windows, and I wanted to know, after a loop was finished, if I could force the program to revert back to the "Sub Main()"

Here is my code, yes it's a bit sloppy, but I've spent a total of 10 hours give or take a few.

```
   Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Clear()
    Console.Title = ("Desktop TBI | Hello " + username)
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    Console.WriteLine("Please select an option, note that this is a work in progress, and will contain more features in the future")
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("                 Type 'File' to create the directory (Important if you want to add plugins)")
    Console.WriteLine("                                    Using Version: " + VersionName)
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    Console.WriteLine("                             Please choose what action you want to do")
    Console.WriteLine("                               Type in 'File' To find the directory")
    Console.WriteLine("                 Type in 'Update' To open the .bat file to download the updates")
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    Console.WriteLine("To create the new path, enter 'CreateDir'")
    REM Begin the part where users can select their code.
    Dim selection As String = Console.ReadLine
    Select Case selection
        REM This allows the creation of a text file.
        Case "File"
            Console.Clear()
            File() REM Private sub selection
            REM Updates their program.
        Case "Username"
            Console.Clear()
            GoTo UserName
            REM Set's their username for the program.
        Case "Update"
            Update()
        Case "KeyList"
            KeyList()
        Case "CreateDir"
            CreateDir()
        Case "SERV_Start"
            Chat_Start_SERV()
            Console.ReadLine()
        Case "PressAKey"
            PressAkey()

    End Select
End Sub
Private Sub File()
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Desktop\Test.txt"
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim aryText(4) As String

    aryText(0) = "Mary WriteLine"
    aryText(1) = "Had"
    aryText(2) = "Another"
    aryText(3) = "Little"
    aryText(4) = "One"

    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)

    For i = 0 To 4
        objWriter.WriteLine(aryText(i))
    Next

    objWriter.Close()
    MsgBox("Your file has been loaded.")

End Sub
'State the version name
Dim version As String = "1"
Dim ICollection As String = Console.ReadLine
Private Sub Update()
    If version Then
        Console.WriteLine("It appears you are using 1.0 version, do you want to scan for updates?")
        Console.WriteLine("Please note, this will take you to a .batch file. Do not edit any of the content")
        Console.WriteLine("As it could potentially mess up the file")
        Select Case ICollection
            Case "Yes"
                GoTo site
            Case "No"


        End Select
site:
        Process.Start("C:\VBTBI\Programs\Update.bat")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a Do Until loop around the code inside sub Main.  Have the exit condition as selection="Quit"

```
Sub Main() 
    Do
    'all the code in sub Main' 
    Until selection="Quit"
End Sub
```

Then add Quit in the list of options in your console's main text

Comment: Thank you! it was bugging me for a while ;-;